# how to create a clickable event for pane in ui automation?

Tags: c#, vb.net

when i try to create a clickable event for a pane it is giving me error like "cannot implicitly convert type'system.windows.point' to 'system.drawing.point" here is my code

```
PropertyCondition buttonCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "custLogin");
var click = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, buttonCondition);
 System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = click.GetClickablePoint();
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, new IntPtr());
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,new IntPtr());
```

I am newer to this so please help me

Comment: You are using the wrong types; just like the error says. You are trying to assign a value of type `System.Windows.Point` to a property (or variable) of type `System.Drawing.Point`. I assume the method `GetClickablePoint` returns a `System.Windows.Point`. The `Position` propety of `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` actually is of the type `System.Drawing.Point`.